# How does SQL Server store covering indexes?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

With covering indexes in SQL Server, say your primary index is an INT, and you have include (a, b, c) where a and b are also INT's and c is an `nvarchar(max)`. Does SQL Server store the whole `nvarchar(max)` in the index, or, does it store a reference pointer to the `nvarchar(max)`?

Comment: The answer is probably "it depends". And upon what it depends is how much you actually put into that BLOB column. ie, if I put more than could ever fit on one page, it will necessarily spill. But what if I just put `N'aaa'`? But there's no need to speculate - fire up `dbcc ind` and `dbcc page` against a test table and experiment with different scenarios!

Comment: `max` types such as `varchar` `nvarchar` `varbinary` and `xml` go in-row if less than the max row size of 8kb, otherwise they go into a separate LOB heap, and use a pointer reference.